# My code creates the concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, exception, concurrency

I have a void and when it's called it sends a concurrent modification exception. I cannot understand why I keep getting it, even though I do not see any concurrent modifications being carried out.

```
public static void destroyPlayingGame() {
    for (CastleWarBarricade npc : playingGame.barricades) {
         playingGame.removeBarricade(CastleWars.SARADOMIN, npc);
         playingGame.removeBarricade(CastleWars.ZAMORAK, npc);
    }
    for (WorldObject object : playingGame.spawnedObjects)
        World.destroySpawnedObject(object, false);
    for (CastleWarBarricade npc : playingGame.barricades)
        npc.finish();

    playingGame.spawnedObjects.clear();
    playingGame.barricades.clear();
    playingGame.cancel();
    playingGame = null;
    refreshAllPlayersTime();
    leavePlayersSafely();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concurrent modifications must be happening in one of the method calls in the loops.  For instance, `removeBarricade` could remove the `npc` object from the `playingGame.barricades` collection.  THAT is a concurrent modification.

> Then what way should I do this?

Change `removeBarricade` so that it doesn't remove the object from the collection, and then do it something like this instead:

```
for (Iterator<CastleWarBarricade> it = playingGame.barricades.iterator();
     it.hasNext(); ) {
     CastleWarBarricade npc = it.next();
     if (playingGame.removeBarricade(CastleWars.SARADOMIN, npc) ||
         playingGame.removeBarricade(CastleWars.ZAMORAK, npc)) {
         it.remove();
     }
}
```

Alternatively, build a collection of things to be removed, and remove them with a `removeAll` call ... after the loop ends!

Comment: Then what way should I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't modify a Collection with in a for-each statement

```
for (CastleWarBarricade npc : playingGame.barricades) {...}
```

Modifying your playingGame collection within the above statement is illegal

**Updated**

You can a magnitude of choices.

You could use a `for-next` loop...

```
for (int index = 0; index < playingGame.barricades.size(); index++) {
    CastleWarBarricade npc = playingGame.barricades.get(index);
    playingGame.removeBarricade(CastleWars.SARADOMIN, npc);
    playingGame.removeBarricade(CastleWars.ZAMORAK, npc);
}
```

You could convert the original collection to an array and use a `for-each`

```
CastleWarBarricade[] values = playingGame.barricades.toArray(new CastleWarBarricade[playingGame.barricades.size]);
for (CastleWarBarricade npc : values) {
    playingGame.removeBarricade(CastleWars.SARADOMIN, npc);
    playingGame.removeBarricade(CastleWars.ZAMORAK, npc);
}
```

Comment: Whats the best way to handle this then?

Comment: You can use a for-next loop, or, as I prefer, use the toArray method of the Collection and use it in the for-each